# Conditions in do-while with || vs. &&

Tags: c, loops, conditional-statements, nested-loops, do-while

```
main()
{
    int x, y, userInput;
    do {
        {   printf("Input a number: \n");
        scanf("%i", &userInput);
        }
    } while (userInput < 1 || userInput > 50);
```

The while end condition works with `||`, I want to understand why it doesn't work with `&&`. `||` allows me to set-up the range between the 0 - 50, If I use `&&` it allows all inputs no restraints. Its very easy to most but I am new and trying to learn the very basics. Appreciate any help!

```
for (x = 1; x <= userInput; x++) {
        for (y = 1; y <= x; y++) {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    PAUSE;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `||` and `&&` don't mean the same thing.

`||` is the logical OR operator, so it makes perfect sense there because you run the loop again only if the input is **not** as per your spec. Wrong input is that where userInput is <1, or where userInput is >50. It is wrong in both cases, but just 1 case is sufficient to make it wrong, so you use OR. It can't be that the vaue is both <1 and >50 at the same time, so the AND operator (`&&`) there would always return false.

If you want to use `&&` to say "run the loop again only if the number is **not** between 1 and 50" you must change the comparison to:

- `while (!(userInput >= 1 && userInput <= 50));`.

Note that `!` is the NOT operator.

Comment: Note that `!` is logical NOT, but there is also `~` for bitwise NOT.

Answer (score 2):

You want to loop while the input is below one or the input is greater than 50.

If you use and, the condition will never be true, as the input cannot be lower than 1 and greater than 50.

Comment: Thanks Matthieu! Oh I see it cant be less than && greater than at the same time, therefore it wont listen to what I need which is to stay between 1 and 50. So using the || loop will allow the program to run only when between the set ranges, but && will allow all numbers disregarding the range. Maybe its my English, which is not proper even when I write "between 1 and 50" I just assumed && would work.

Comment: Yes, but the loop is while it's not between 1 and 50. And this is solved with the OR operator. Boolean algebra.